# Is throwing an exception an anti-pattern here?

Tags: java, programming-practices, coding-style, exceptions, anti-patterns

I just had a discussion over a design choice after a code review. I wonder what your opinions are.

There's this `Preferences` class, which is a bucket for key-value pairs. Null values are legal (that's important). We expect that certain values may not be saved yet, and we want to handle these cases automatically by initializing them with predefined default value when requested.

The discussed solution used following pattern (NOTE: this is *not* the actual code, obviously - it's simplified for illustrative purposes):

```
public class Preferences {
    // null values are legal
    private Map<String, String> valuesFromDatabase;

    private static Map<String, String> defaultValues;

    class KeyNotFoundException extends Exception {
    }

    public String getByKey(String key) {
        try {
            return getValueByKey(key);
        } catch (KeyNotFoundException e) {
            String defaultValue = defaultValues.get(key);
            valuesFromDatabase.put(key, defaultvalue);
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    private String getValueByKey(String key) throws KeyNotFoundException {
        if (valuesFromDatabase.containsKey(key)) {
            return valuesFromDatabase.get(key);
        } else {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

It was criticized as an anti-pattern - [abusing exceptions to control the flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/31260). `KeyNotFoundException` - brought to life for that one use case only - is never going to be seen out of the scope of this class.

It's essentially two methods playing fetch with it merely to communicate something to each other.

The key not being present in the database isn't something alarming, or exceptional - we expect this to occur whenever a new preference setting is added, hence the mechanism that gracefully initializes it with a default value if needed.

The counterargument was that `getValueByKey` - the private method - as defined right now has no natural way of informing the public method about *both* the value, and whether the key was there. (If it wasn't, it has to be added so that the value can be updated).

Returning `null` would be ambiguous, since `null` is a perfectly legal value, so there's no telling whether it meant that the key wasn't there, or if there was a `null`.

`getValueByKey` would have to return some sort of a `Tuple<Boolean, String>`, the bool set to true if the key is already there, so that we can distinguish between `(true, null)` and `(false, null)`. (An `out` parameter could be used in C#, but that's Java).

Is this a nicer alternative? Yes, you'd have to define some single-use class to the effect of `Tuple<Boolean, String>`, but then we're getting rid of `KeyNotFoundException`, so that kind of balances out. We're also avoiding the overhead of handling an exception, although it's not significant in practical terms - there are no performance considerations to speak of, it's a client app and it's not like user preferences will be retrieved millions of times per second.

A variation of this approach could use Guava's `Optional<String>` (Guava is already used throughout the project) instead of some custom `Tuple<Boolean, String>`, and then we can differentiate between `Optional.<String>absent()` and "proper" `null`. It still feels hackish, though, for reasons that are easy to see - introducing two levels of "nullness" seem to abuse the concept that stood behind creating `Optional`s in the first place.

Another option would be to explicitly check whether the key exists (add a `boolean containsKey(String key)` method and call `getValueByKey` only if we have already asserted that it exists).

Finally, one could also inline the private method, but the actual `getByKey` is somewhat more complex than my code sample, thus inlining would make it look quite nasty.

I may be splitting hairs here, but I'm curious what you would bet on to be closest to best practice in this case. I didn't find an answer in Oracle's or Google's style guides.

Is using exceptions like in the code sample an anti-pattern, or is it acceptable given that alternatives aren't very clean, either? If it is, under what circumstances would it be fine? And vice versa?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I've been told that Exceptions should only be used in exceptional cases. How do I know if my case is exceptional?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184654/ive-been-told-that-exceptions-should-only-be-used-in-exceptional-cases-how-do)

Comment: @GlenH7 the accepted (and highest voted) answer sums up that "you should use them [exceptions] in cases when they make error handling easier with less code clutter". I guess I'm asking here whether the alternatives that I listed should be considered "less code clutter".

Comment: I retracted my VTC - you're asking for something related to, but different than the duplicate I suggested.

Comment: @GlenH7 thanks. I believe the answers here add value beyond the content of the other question. I probably could've given the question a less generic title, but I couldn't think of one at the moment...

Comment: What do you mean by "_inline_ the private method" ?

Comment: I think the question becomes more interesting when `getValueByKey` is also public.

Comment: For future reference, you did the right thing. This would have been off topic on Code Review because it's example code.

Comment: Just to chime in --- this is perfectly idiomatic Python, and would (I think) be the preferred way to handle this problem in that language. Obviously, though, different languages have different conventions.

Comment: note that if you *would* implement it like this, you'd want to define your exception in a way that it'd have no stack trace, making it a lot lighter than a regular exception - that takes care of most of the weight associated with exceptions.

Comment: valuesFromDatabase can have null values.  Can valuesFromDatabase have the empty string,`""`, as a value?  If so does this have a different semantic meaning than a null value?

Comment: I know that hardly anyone cares anymore but seriously. If you were implementing something like Redis would you really do a contains() call and then a get() call? Both calls need to hash or tree-search. The duplication is a pointless waste of time. If you possibly can, return the value and a "found" flag.

Comment: The flaw in the map of requiring two lookups to distinguish between the entry being there, but null, and the entry not being there, is your problem more than anything.  A wrapper that makes map not suck, and stores a `Map<K, Optional<V>>`, converts incoming `null` `V` values to absent and provides getters that reverse the absent<->null pair (so absent means key was not found, and null means null was stored, instead of two meanings for one flag value (ik)), would be internally ugly but at least would remove the demon that is that horrid `Map` interface from your code.  But that is just me.

Comment: Don't worry about Google's style guide; it's full of nonsense. For one, they ban all exceptions, so that immediately doesn't help you.

Answer (score 78):

Yes, your colleague is right: that is bad code. If an error can be handled locally, then it should be handled immediately. An exception should not be thrown and then handled immediately.

This is much cleaner then your version (the `getValueByKey()` method is removed) :

```
public String getByKey(String key) {
    if (valuesFromDatabase.containsKey(key)) {
        return valuesFromDatabase.get(key);
    } else {
        String defaultValue = defaultValues.get(key);
        valuesFromDatabase.put(key, defaultvalue);
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

An exception should be thrown only if you do not know how to resolve the error locally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the record, I'm this colleague (I didn't like the original code), I just phrased the question neutrally so that it wasn't loaded :)

Comment: First sign of insanity: you start talking to yourself.

Comment: @BЈовић: well, in that case I think it is ok, but what if you need two variants - one method retrieving the value without autocreation of missing keys, and one with? What do you think is the cleanest (and DRY) alternative then?

Comment: @DocBrown Trick question? No idea. I would probably move the else block into a separate function, where it is decided whether to insert or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey :) someone else authored this piece of code, an actual separate person, I was the reviewer

Comment: @BЈовић: my question was serious. I tried to give my own answer for that case.

Comment: A variation of this pattern (and to avoid having to keep a separate default values object around and perform a second lookup), you can pass into the method your default value, and return out either the looked-up value or the default. Like: `getByKey(final String key, final String default)`

Comment: I agree, this is how the code should read, it's clear and concise what this method does. The "nasty" (as OP says) implementation of the key/value store should not be part of this function, it should be abstracted into it's own class if necessary.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Android™ developers talk to themselves all the time. This is a sign of professionalism.

Comment: I can't fully agree with this. Coming from python, I use exceptions quite frequently

Comment: @Alvaro, using exceptions frequently isn't a problem.  Using exceptions badly is a problem, regardless of language.

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't call this use of Exceptions an anti-pattern, just not the best solution to the problem of communicating a complex result.

The best solution (assuming you're still on Java 7) would be to use Guava's Optional; I disagree that it's use in this case would be hackish. It seems to me, based on [Guava's extended explanation of Optional](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained), that this is a perfect example of when to use it. You're differentiating between "no value found" and "value of null found".

Comment: I don't think `Optional` can hold null. `Optional.of()` only takes a not-null reference and `Optional.fromNullable()` treats null as "value not present".

Comment: @Navin it can't hold null, but you have `Optional.absent()` at your disposal. And so, `Optional.fromNullable(string)` will be equal to `Optional.<String>absent()` if `string` was null, or `Optional.of(string)` if it wasn't.

Comment: @KonradMorawski I thought the problem in the OP was that you could not distinguish between a null string and a nonexistant string without throwing an exception. `Optional.absent()` covers one of these scenarios. How do you represent the other one?

Comment: @Navin with an actual `null`.

Comment: @KonradMorawski AH! Ok, so that's what I was missing.

Comment: @KonradMorawski: That sounds like a really bad idea. I can hardly think of a clearer way to say "this method never returns `null`!" than to declare it as returning `Optional<...>` . . .

Answer (score 8):

Since there's no performance considerations and it's an implementation detail, it ultimately doesn't matter which solution you choose. But I have to agree it's bad style; the key being absent is something that you know *will* happen, and you don't even handle it more than one call up the stack, which is where exceptions are most useful.

The tuple approach is a bit hacky because the second field is meaningless when the boolean is false. Checking if the key exists beforehand is silly because the map is looking up the key twice. (Well, you're already doing that, so in this case thrice.) The `Optional` solution is a perfect fit for the problem. It might seem a bit ironic to store a `null` in an `Optional`, but if that's what the user wants to do, you can't say no.

As noted by Mike in the comments, there's an issue with this; neither Guava nor Java 8's `Optional` allow storing `null`s. Thus you'd need to roll your own which -- while straightforward -- involves a fair amount of boilerplate, so might be overkill for something that will only be used once internally. You could also change the map's type to `Map<String, Optional<String>>`, but handling `Optional<Optional<String>>`s gets awkward.

A reasonable compromise might be to keep the exception, but acknowledge its role as an "alternative return". Create a new checked exception with the stack trace disabled, and throw a pre-created instance of it which you can keep in a static variable. This is cheap -- [possibly as cheap as a local branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075127/1272233) -- and you can't forget to handle it, so the lack of stack trace isn't an issue.

Comment: Well, in reality it's only `Map<String, String>` on the database table level, because the `values` column has to be of one type. There's a wrapper DAO layer that strong-types each key-value pair, though. But I omitted this for clarity. (Of course you could have a one-row table with n columns instead, but then adding each new value requires updating the table schema, so removing the complexity associated with having to parse them comes at the cost of introducing another complexity elsewhere).

Comment: Good point about the tuple. Indeed, what would `(false, "foo")` be supposed to mean?

Comment: At least with Guava's Optional, trying to put a null in results in an exception. You'd have to use Optional.absent().

Comment: @MikePartridge Good point. An ugly workaround would be to change the map to `Map<String, Optional<String>>` and then you'd end up with `Optional<Optional<String>>`. A less confusing solution would be to roll your own Optional that allows `null`, or a similar algebraic data type that disallows `null` but has 3 states - absent, null, or present. Both are simple to implement, though the amount of boilerplate involved is high for something that will only be used internally.

Comment: Why would handling `Optional<Optional<String>>` be awkward?

Comment: @valenterry The type is annoyingly long and it's not immediately obvious that the an absent value in the outer level means "not found" while in the inner level it means "null".

Comment: If its too long, wrap it and delegate. It's just what it is. Also, using null is even more meaningless then a nested option. So either create custom wrapping types to make it more clear and easy to handle or use `Optional`. Using null is the worst option.

Comment: @valenterry Wrapping and delegating still suffers from resulting in a lot of boilerplate for relatively little payoff. If he *could* use `null`, it wouldn't be a problem *in this particular case* because 1) `null` is what the user wants and 2) he just needs to store and retrieve the values, not examine them. There's no risk of him getting a `NullPointerException` and he could store and retrieve values directly. With a nested `Optional` he has to take additional steps to convert to and from `null` with no real benefit. If he could change the public method to return `Optional` I'd agree.

Comment: @Doval It results in boilerplate but this is Javas fault. Also I don't think the user wants `null` or did I overread anything? But yeah, it all comes out to if he can change the return type. If he can't, that will remain the root of all evil.

Comment: "Since there's no performance considerations and it's an implementation detail, it ultimately doesn't matter which solution you choose" - Except that if you were using C# using an exception will annoy anyone who is trying to debug with "Break when an exception is Thrown" is turned on for CLR exceptions.

Comment: @Stephen using this option, you can still filter out specific exceptions (although there's always that first time when you hit it)

Comment: @KonradMorawski you can, but it's still annoying. The .NET framework does this in XML handling code and it bothers me every time.

Answer (score 5):

> There's this Preferences class, which is a bucket for key-value pairs. ***Null values are legal*** (that's important). We expect that certain values may not be saved yet, and we want to handle these cases automatically by initializing them with predefined default value when requested.

The problem is exactly this. But you already posted the solution yourself:

> A variation of this approach could use Guava's Optional (Guava is already used throughout the project) instead of some custom Tuple, ***and then we can differentiate between Optional.absent() and "proper" null***. It still feels hackish, though, for reasons that are easy to see - introducing two levels of "nullness" seem to abuse the concept that stood behind creating Optionals in the first place.

However, don't use `null` *or* `Optional`. You can and  should use `Optional` only. For your "hackish" feeling, just use it nested, so you end up with `Optional<Optional<String>>` which makes it explicit that there might a key in the database (first option layer) and that it might contain a predefined value (second option layer).

This approach is better than using exceptions and it is quite easy to understand as long as `Optional` is not new to you.

Also please note that `Optional` has some comfort functions, so that you don't have to do all the work yourself. These include:

- `static static <T> Optional<T> fromNullable(T nullableReference)` to convert your database input to the `Optional` types
- `abstract T or(T defaultValue)` to get the key value of the inner option layer or (if not present) get your default key value

Comment: `Optional<Optional<String>>` looks evil, although it has some charm I have to admit : )

Comment: Can you explain further why it looks evil? It is actually the same pattern as `List<List<String>>`. You can of course (if the language allows) make a new type like `DBConfigKey` which wrapps the `Optional<Optional<String>>` and makes it more readable if you prefer that.

Comment: @valenterry It's very different. A list of lists is a legitimate way of storing some kinds of data; an optional of an optional is an atypical way of indicating two kinds of problems the data could have.

Comment: An option of an option is like a list of lists where each list has one or no elements. It's essentially the same. Just because it is not used often *in Java* does not mean it is inherently bad.

Comment: I guess a new optional-like type with three options "not configured", "configured as null" and "configured as non-null with value x" might be clearer than `Optional<Optional<T>>`. (Though the question is: What is the meaning of "configured as null"?)

Comment: @valenterry evil in the sense that Jon Skeet means; so not outright bad, but a bit wicked, "clever code". I guess it's just somewhat baroque, an optional of an optional. It's not explicitly clear which level of optionalness represents what.  I'd have a double take if I encountered it in somebody's code. You might be right that it feels weird just because it's unusual, unidiomatic. Perhaps it's nothing fancy for a functional language programmer, with their monads and all. While I wouldn't go for it myself, I still +1'd your answer because it's interesting

Comment: @KonradMorawski Where is the difference to a nested list then? I don't quite understand what you guys mean. =/ What I understand, however, is the problem of not knowing what level is representing which business logic. (but again, this is the same with nested lists too) Therefore, wrap the inner option into a more meaningfull type.

Comment: @valenterry nested list is also dubious to me. It's just that I've seen it once or twice, so it doesn't feel so alien. But in this case I'd would also prefer to wrap it in a domain specific type, like you say. It's probably better. Not exactly a nested list, but Google's Guava provides a `Multimap` type that serves a similar purpose. To quote the docs, `Every experienced Java programmer has, at one point or another, implemented a Map<K, List<V>> or Map<K, Set<V>>, and dealt with the awkwardness of that structure [...] A Multimap is a general way to associate keys with arbitrarily many values`

Answer (score 5):

I know I am late to the party, but anyways your use case resembles how [Java's `Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) lets one define a set of default properties too, which will be checked if there is no corresponding key loaded by the instance.

Looking at how the implementation is done for `Properties.getProperty(String)` (from Java 7):

```
Object oval = super.get(key);
String sval = (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null;
return ((sval == null) && (defaults != null)) ? defaults.getProperty(key) : sval;
```

There really isn't a need to "abuse exceptions to control the flow", as you have quoted.

A similar, but slightly more terse, approach to @BЈовић's answer can also be:

```
public String getByKey(String key) {
    if (!valuesFromDatabase.containsKey(key)) {
        valuesFromDatabase.put(key, defaultValues.get(key));
    }
    return valuesFromDatabase.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Though I think @BЈовић's answer is fine in case `getValueByKey` is needed nowhere else, I don't think your solution is bad in case your program contains both use cases:

- retrieval by key with automatic creation in case the key does not exist beforehand, and
- retrieval without that automatism, without changing anything in the database, repository, or key map (think of `getValueByKey` beeing public, not private)

If this is your situation, and as long as the performance hit is acceptable, I think your proposed solution is fully ok. It has the advantage of avoiding duplication of the retrieval code, it does not rely on third party frameworks, and it is pretty simple (at least in my eyes).

In fact, in such a situation, in depends on the context if a missing key is an "exceptional" situation or not. For a context where it is, something like `getValueByKey` is needed. For a context where automatic key creation is expected, providing a method which reuses the already available function, swallows the exception and provides a different failure behaviour, makes perfectly sense. This can be interpreted as an extension or "decorator" of `getValueByKey`, not so much as a function where the "exception is abused for flow of control".

Of course, there is a third alternative: create a third, private method returning the `Tuple<Boolean, String>`, as you suggested, and reuse this method both in `getValueByKey` and `getByKey`. For a more complicated case that might be indeed the better alternative, but for such a simple case as shown here, this has IMHO a smell of overengineering, and I doubt the code gets really more maintainable that way. I am here with [the topmost answer here by Karl Bielefeldt](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184654/ive-been-told-that-exceptions-should-only-be-used-in-exceptional-cases-how-do):

> "you shouldn't feel bad about using exceptions when it simplifies your code".

Answer (score 4):

`Optional` is the correct solution.  However, if you prefer, there is an alternative which has less of a "two nulls" feel, consider a sentinel.

Define a private static string `keyNotFoundSentinel`, with a value `new String("")`.*

Now the private method can `return keyNotFoundSentinel` rather than `throw new KeyNotFoundException()`.  The public method can check for that value

```
String rval = getValueByKey(key);
if (rval == keyNotFoundSentinel) { // reference equality, not string.equals
    ... // generate default value
} else {
    return rval;
}
```

In reality, `null` is a special case of a sentinel.  It is a sentinel value defined by the language, with a few special behaviors (i.e. well defined behavior if you call a method on `null`).  It just happens to be so useful to have a sentinel like that that nearly ever language uses it.

*  We intentionally use `new String("")` rather than merely `""` to prevent Java from "interning" the string, which would give it the same reference as any other empty string.  Because did this extra step, we are guaranteed that the String referred to by `keyNotFoundSentinel` is a unique instance, which we need to ensure it can never appear in the map itself.

Comment: This, IMHO, is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Learn from the framework that learned from all Java's pain points:

.NET provides two far more elegant solutions to this problem, exemplified by:

- [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault(T default)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d(v=vs.110).aspx)

The latter is very easy to write in Java, the former just requires a "strong reference" helper class.

Comment: A covariance-friendly alternative to the `Dictionary` pattern would be `T TryGetValue(TKey, out bool)`.