# Should service throw exception or return when no items specified for deletion

Tags: c#, exceptions, error-handling

I have a piece of code that can be represented as:

```
public class ItemService {

    public void DeleteItems(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        // Save us from possible NullReferenceException below.
        if(items == null)
            return;

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            // For the purpose of this example, lets say I have to iterate over them.
            // Go to database and delete them.
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering if this is the right approach or should I throw exception. I can avoid exception, because returning would be the same as iterating over an empty collection, meaning, no important code is executed anyway, but on the other hand I'm possibly hiding problems somewhere in the code, because why would anyone want to call `DeleteItems` with `null` parameter? This may indicate that there is a problem somewhere else in the code.

This is a problem I usually have with methods in services, because most of them do something and don't return a result, so if someone passes invalid information then there is nothing for the service to do, so it returns.

Comment: This is just my person opinion, but I've always found it to make most sense that a method should throw an exception when it does something unintended (exceptional). In your case, I would throw an InvalidOperationException if someone tried to delete null/0 items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've been told that Exceptions should only be used in exceptional cases. How do I know if my case is exceptional?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184654/ive-been-told-that-exceptions-should-only-be-used-in-exceptional-cases-how-do)

Comment: @gnat My question is specifically about services, because of how they are used and their purpose. This "duplicate" only talks about the general cases and the main answer even contradicts itself in the context of my exact method.

Comment: Is it possible for the enumerable to be empty instead of null? Would you handle that differently?

Comment: @Falgantil I can see null being worthy of an exception, but I think it's absurd to throw an exception on an empty list.

Comment: @Kevin You're right. I assumed the question was related to some sort of Web API request, in which case I think it would be silly to request a service do "0 deletes". But it doesn't say anything about Web API's, I guess I've just been working a lot with that lately. My mistake. Null is exceptional, 0 is acceptable ^^

Comment: Is there a reason you don't return the number of items deleted?  Then, perhaps, the caller's "handle whatever value/exception comes out of this service" wrapper can discover they're calling your service with null pointers or empty lists.  (This is related to my frequently justified belief that services don't actually do what I call them to do, just some baffling subset.  Figuring this out requires more feedback than `void`.)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

These are two different questions.

Should you accept `null`? That depends on your general policy about `null` in the code base. In my opinion, banning `null` everywhere except where explicitly documented is a very good practice, but it's even better practice to stick to the convention your code base already has.

Should you accept the empty collection? In my opinion: YES, absolutely. It is much more effort to restrict all callers to non-empty collections than to do the mathematically right thing - even if it surprises some developers who are iffy with the concept of zero.

Comment: Throwing exception means wrapping every call to service with try/catch (which I already mostly do), logging the error and checking for null before accessing service. This clutters the code and becomes boilerplate for many methods, but I agree. If there is one approach to be used across the project then I would go with exceptions. Throwing exceptions expresses method's intent better than hiding invalid input.

Comment: @FCin Sounds like your calls to the service could be turned into a generic wrapper method that will do the try/catch and some null checking for you. It will reduce the clutter while still providing more robust error handling.

Comment: In any case, if you're going to throw, then there's not all that much utility in throwing `AhaINoticedYouPassingInNullException` when the runtime already provides you with the facility of throwing `NullReferenceException` for you, without you writing any code at all. There is some utility (e.g. your code coverage tool will tell you whether or not you have a unit test for passing in null in the former case but not the latter), but neither exception should be try/caught on every call to the service, because it's *usually* a programmer error.

Comment: ... you should only be immediately catching exceptions raised due to sketchy parameters, if you know that what you're passing in is null in some expected case, and you actively want the function you're calling to validate it for you. Like Kilian says in the answer, your general policy might be to ban null everywhere it's not explicitly allowed. Then you wouldn't catch `NullReferenceException` or `AhaINoticedYouPassingInNullException` anywhere except at high-level disaster-recovery code. And that exception handler should probably create a bug report :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop But if I use my service in many controllers, then every call to the service has to have try/catch with it, because it can throw ArgumentNullException, so it becomes boilerplate if I don't want to do anything with it, but just log it and continue

Comment: @FCin: your interface design should match what users actually need out of the service. So if every caller is going to put try/catch around this, then either this method or some convenience method alongside it should check for and ignore null, because that's what your public demands. However, as Kilian says, it usually works out better to treat propagating nulls as a programming error, and *not* try to continue at every call site. For that matter, what if the service on which this method gets called is `null` -- do the controllers contain boilerplate to catch and continue in that case too?

Comment: ... if so, then it does seem like the code base is consistently treating missing components as an expected condition that you should handle at low level and continue. You can reasonably ask, "whose responsibility is it to provide a service and an enumerable so that this operation can go ahead?". If the answer is "someone", then your function is *checking preconditions*, and the result of a failed precondition normally would be an exception caught at high level, not at every call. If the required stuff for the operation is truly optional, then your function is *handling an expected use case*.

Comment: To be clear, in case this isn't obvious: not every call site should catch every exception possibly thrown by the function it's calling. So if you figure out *why* every call site needs that boilerplate, and it's a good reason, then you've figured out why it's helpful to provide a method that swallows `null`, and you can go ahead and swallow `null`.

Comment: If these rules leave you in doubt, consider the constraints of evolving an API in a backward compatible way. You can *stop* throwing exceptions and be backward compatible, but but you cannot *start* throwing exceptions for arguments that used to be accepted.

Comment: Explicitly throwing an `ArgumentNullException` is superior to allowing interior code to throw a `NullReferenceException` -- purely looking at the exception message it is obvious that it is an input error rather than a logic error in the method body at the throw site, and ensuring early-exit means that you are more likely to have left other data in a valid state rather than partially mutated from an unexpected null later on.

Comment: @FCin "_every call to the service has to have try/catch with it, because it can throw ArgumentNullException_": [Eric Lippert would define an `ArgumentNullException` as boneheaded](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) - you shouldn't be catching them, you should be fixing the code that causes them. (And I agree with him)

Comment: @PhilipC Thank you for the link. I was not aware of that you should not catch exceptions such as `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: @SteveJessop This makes sense, I guess I was just too scared to have possible uncaught exceptions in production.

Comment: @FCin It's fine for there to be `void main() { try { RunTheProgram(); } catch (Exception e) { LogAndDieCleanly(e) } }` or similar, to improve on the platform's default unhandled exception UX

Comment: And in the case of a service, you might want `LogAndDieCleanly()` to arrange to start a new copy of the service. Ideally you want the current process to exit, though, because whoever wrote the code doesn't understand what went wrong, and therefore you can't rely on anything any more.

Comment: @PhilipC: Weirdly, Lippert doesn't explain why C# cannot just get rid of the exogenous `FileNotFoundException` by the library providing a Try version that uses its return value to indicate when the file doesn't exist. AFACIT the difference between an Exogenous vs Vexing exception, is whether or not  Eric Lippert considers the failure case to be dramatic enough to throw an exception ;-) An exception that's exogonous at one call site is vexing at a different call site, and in some cases an exception that's boneheaded at one call site is merely vexing (or even exogonous) at another.

Comment: ... so for another example he lists, if you're doing one division and you end up throwing and catching `DivideByZeroException`, that might well be boneheaded. If you have 200 lines implementing some algorithm from an academic paper, then putting a try/catch around the whole thing rather than cluttering every use of `/` with a check-for-zero, conceivably will improve both the readability *and* performance of your code, and will also avoid the risk of accidentally missing one. The same could be true of code where a lot of things might be null, vs code where only one thing might be null.

Answer (score 9):

### Null Value

As @KilianFoth already said, stick to your general policy. If that is to treat `null` as a "shorthand" for an empty list, do it that way.

If you don't have a consistent policy on `null` values, I'd recommend the following one:

`null` should be reserved to represent situations that can't be expressed by the "normal" type, e.g. using `null` to represent "I don't know". And that's a good choice, as everybody trying to carelessly use this value will get an exception, which is the right thing.

Using `null` as a shorthand for an empty list does not qualify that way, as there already is a perfect representation, being a list with zero elements. And it's a technically bad choice, as it forces every part of your code dealing with lists to check for the valid shorthand `null`.

### Empty List

For a `DeleteItems()` method, passing an empty list effectively means to do nothing. I'd allow that as an argument, not throwing an exception, just returning quickly.

Of course, the caller could check for zero elements first and skip the `DeleteItems()` call in that case. If we're talking about a web API, for efficiency reasons the caller **should** actually do that to avoid unneccessary traffic and round-trip latencies. But I don't think your API should enforce that.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an exception and handle nulls in the calling code.

As a design rule try to avoid null as parameter values. It will reduce NullPointerExceptions in general, as nulls will really be an exception.

Besides that, look at the rest of your code. If this is a common pattern in your project then stay consistent.

Comment: I'm in the middle of "shaping" how my services are structured, so some refactoring might be required to throw on invalid input, but not a lot. But I agree with your point that nulls will become an exception once I start throwing instead of hiding them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, throwing exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations, i.e. if the code has no reasonable course of action to take in the current context.

You can apply that thought process to this situation. Given that this is a public class with a public method, you have a public API, and in theory no control over what gets passed to it.

Your code has no context about what is calling it (as it shouldnt), and there is nothing you can reasonably do with a null value. This would certainly be a candidate for an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: "if the code has no reasonable course of action to take in the current context". But my thinking is, it has reasonable course of action, which is to return void. It does exactly the same thing as when passing empty collection, so if I allow empty collection then why would I not allow `null`.

Comment: @FCin Because of an empty collection you know it is empty. With `null` you have no collection. If the calling code is supposed/expected to supply a collection to the method, there is something wrong, so you should throw. The only reason to treat a null the same as an empty collection is if you could reasonably expect the calling code to produce null collections. As other answers noted, most of the times, something being `null` is an anomaly. If you treat these the same as empty collections, you are potentially ignoring a problem elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @FCin: also, if you take `null` to mean empty, that's context-specific to this method. Somewhere else in the same code base, you might have an `IEnumerable` or `IContainer` parameter that does some sort of filtering, `null` might mean "no filter" (allow everything) whereas an empty filter means allow nothing. And in another place, `null` might explicitly mean "I don't know". So, given that `null` doesn't always mean quite the same thing everywhere, it's a good idea not to invent any meaning for it at all unless that meaning is necessary or at least useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems not to be about exceptions, but about `null` being a valid argument.

So, first and foremost you have to decide whether `null` is an allowed value for your the argument of that method. If it is, then you do not need an exception. If it is not, then you do need an exception.

Whether you wish to allow `null`, or not, is debatable, as shown by lots and lots of Google hits about that. Meaning, you will not get a clear answer, and it is somewhat up to opinion and tradition at the place you are working.

Another area of contention is whether a library function should be *really* strict about such things, or as lenient as possible, as long as it is not trying to "fix" erroneous parameters. Compare this to the world of network protocols, mail transfer etc. (which are interface contracts, just like methods in programming). There, usually, the policy is that the sender should conform as strictly as possible to the protocol, while the receiver should go out of their way to be able to work with whatever is coming along.

So you have to decide: Is it really the job of a library method to enforce rather large policy like `null` handling? Especially if your library is used by other people as well (who might have different policies).

I would probably err on the side of allowing `null` values, definining and documenting their semantics (i.e., `null = empty array` in this case), and not throw an exception, *unless* 99% of your other similar code ("library" style code) does it the other way 'round.

Comment: "Is it really the job of a library method to enforce rather large policy like null handling?" -- down that line of thinking lie asserts and debug modes, which allow you to *help* with enforcing a policy, rather than actually enforcing it, if that's what you want to do. So if you're going to swallow `null` on the principle of being liberal in what you accept, then logging or even throwing would be helpful to people whose *intention* is to be strict in what they pass in, but who have messed up both their code and their unit tests to the extent that they pass `null` anyway.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I don't really know if you're arguing against the spirit of my answer, or whether you are continuing along its line. That said, I'm not suggesting to simply swallow `null`, but to declare it openly in the contract of the method that it is acceptable (or not, depending on whatever solution the OP comes up), and then the question whether to throw an exception (or not) solves itself.